# Javascript : Como fazer um random com base na hora?

Tags: javascript

Como adicionar o valor ao texto?

E como fazer ele ficar neste formato? por exemplo: ADQ2018060601513610 (com 20 caracteres)

Exemplo:

```js
function insertNewAdq() {
    var pk = document.getElementById("txtPk").style;
    pk.value = ("ADQ" + (Math.random() * 10000000000));
    console.log(pk.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="txtPk" class="txtPk_adq" name="name_txt" style=" width:100px;" type="text"><br>
<button onclick="insertNewAdq()"> Teste </button>
```

Comment: é um random ou um número baseado na data/hora?

Comment: um número randomico baseado na data/hora/min/seg/miliseg

Comment: A versão que eu fiz está errada, gostaria de saber como fazer desta outra forma e como atribuir ao text

Comment: não seria bem um random então, mas para gerar esse número no formato que você quer, coloquei na resposta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o método `toISOString` e depois remova o que não for números:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

```js
var data = new Date();
console.log(data.toISOString());
console.log(data.toISOString().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''));
console.log("ADQ" + data.toISOString().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''));
```

Comment: Entendi, valeu pela explicação, vou estudar mais sobre esse toIsoString, obrigado !!

Comment: tem outros métodos como o `toDateString` que pode informar o format por região (pt-BR, en-US, etc). Já o formato ISO já é praticamente o que você precisa, só remover os caracteres que não forem números

Answer (score 2):

Gerado um número aleatório de 2 dígitos e concatenado a data formatada, conforme seu exemplo, segue:

```js
var d = new Date();
var nAleatorio = (Math.random() * 89)+10
var nAleatorio = nAleatorio .toFixed(0).split('.');

console.log('Número aleatório: '+ nAleatorio);
console.log('Data formatada: '+d.toDate('yyyymmddhhiiss'));
console.log('ADQ'+d.toDate('yyyymmddhhiiss')+ nAleatorio);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Lautert/helpers/master/javascript.helpers.js"></script>
```